# Server error when sending POST request to hosted fastapi

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I have a simple Fastapi where am expecting python dictionary or json data.
I can POST and GET data when running on local server. I hosted same api on **https://deta.sh** but i can only send **GET** request. **POST** request is returning `status code 500`.
I tried hosting the same api on **Heroku** but i get `status code 503`

*here is the sample code:*

`models.py`

```
class DictType(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Text(SIZE)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return value
    
    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return value

class DictTransactionBase(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Transactions"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    Body = Column(DictType())
```

`schemas.py`

```
class DictTransactionModel(BaseModel):
    Body: dict = {}

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

`main.py`

```
@app.post('/api/v1/send/transactions/', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_transaction(trans: schema.DictTransactionModel, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    results = models.DictTransactionBase(**trans.dict())
    db.add(results)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(results)
    return results
```

Above code runs on a local machine and **POST** data is saved to SQLite database.
What would be the reason **POST** request is failing on the deployed API.

Comment: Either service should give you the actual log from your service so that you can see what is causing the service to fail - a 500 error indicates that there's been an Python exception raised or something similar.

Comment: you should use module `logging` to write some information in file - to see which line is executed and what you have in variables. And you could also use `try/except` to catch error and save in `log`.

Comment: to use module `SQLite` in Python it needs also C/C++ library `sqlite`  and maybe server doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, micros only support read-only SQLite, which you could deploy with your code. You can use Deta Base instead of SQLite.